# ImportError: No module named urllib3 while installing urllib3

Tags: python, pip, urllib3

I am working on macOS 10.12.6 (16G29).

Within the installation of cx_Oracle with pip, I am getting the following error:

```
 ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

Quite obviously, I go with urllib3 installation (`pip install urllib3`), but I’m getting the same error.

To tell the truth, that makes me literally crazy. I`m quite new to all this stuff, so any help will be highly appreciated! Any additional information from me on the topic will follow, if needed.

Comment: `urllib3` !== `urlib3`  Is it possible you mis-typed  ?

Comment: @SherylHohman nope. urllib3 it is :)
and thanks btw! corrected the question!

Comment: Please copy-paste the *exact* command that you typed and the full error log (all the gibberish in your command prompt, it contains useful information for diagnosis). Also, the output of `which pip` and `which python`. Also, preventively, how did you install Python on your computer?